# No assembly found containing a Startup or [AssemblyName].Startup class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, startup

I've tried resolving this from answers in other and similar posts, but no luck.
I'm Using MVC 5, framework 4.8 latest VS2017.

Thanks

My Config is:  (including other attempts)

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <!--<add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />-->
        <add key="owin:HandleAllRequests" value="true"/>
        <!--<add key="owin:AppStartup" value="Api.xxx" />-->
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Startup class is:

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(Api.xxx.Startup))]
namespace Api.xxx
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Allow all origins
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            ….
        }
    }
}
```

and Api is:

```
namespace Api.xxx
{
    [Route("values")]
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        private static readonly Random _random = new Random();

        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            var random = new Random();
            return new[]
            {
                _random.Next(0, 10).ToString(),
                _random.Next(0, 10).ToString()
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change

`[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(Api.xxx.Startup))]`

to

`[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(Api.xxx.Startup))]`

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/owin-startup-class-detection

Comment: Actually both work,..the intellisense suggested the same. I had (idiot that I am) forgotten to add this project into my solution multi project settings. But thank You. it is also correct and accepted as such.